# TYPO3: What means "Disable override demand"?

Tags: plugins, configuration, typo3, overriding

What means the TYPO3 configuration "**Disable override demand**"? Sometimes plugins can have this configuration. Can anyone explain it in two or three sentences? Translations in my language are not satisfactory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't a convention, but rather an implementation that depends on each extension, but I assume you mean EXT:news so I will use that as example.

Disabling override demands means users can't override the settings you (the editor) defined in the plugin instance, when they view the plugin rendered in the frontend. So for example, disabling this means things like filtering and sorting will not be possible - the filtering and sorting you decided will always be used.

Take this with a grain of salt though. There could be some arguments which are exempt from being disabled - as stated, the exact implementation may differ and you need to check the individual extensions' documentation for a detailed description of the behavior.

Comment: Thank you @Claus, this helps me a lot. And yes, you are right, I speak from the extension EXT:news.